# How to send a message without spamming it ?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm having a problem since whenever I run this code it spams my cellphone with messaged with " Check In Success" I only want it to send it 1 time when the location coordinates is the same or almost the same with the lastknown coordinate.

Here's the code :

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "Message recieved";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(isMyServiceRunning(context)) { 
            Bundle pudsBundle = intent.getExtras();
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) pudsBundle.get("pdus");
            SmsMessage messages = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);
            Log.i(TAG, messages.getMessageBody());


            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            // Geocoder geocoder;
            String bestProvider;
            // List<Address> user = null;
            double lat;
            double lng;

            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            bestProvider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
            Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

            if(location != location)
            {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage("09164232662", null, "You Have Successfully reached your target Location" , null, null);
            }

            /*else
            {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage("09164232662", null, "Please Walk a few more meters in order to reach the designated location" , null, null);
            }*/


            /*Toast.makeText(
                    context,
                    "FROM: " + messages.getOriginatingAddress() + "time: "
                            + messages.getTimestampMillis() + "SMS Received : "
                            + messages.getMessageBody(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/

            String date=String.valueOf(messages.getTimestampMillis());
            HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
            data.put("phone", messages.getOriginatingAddress());
            data.put("text", messages.getMessageBody());
            //data.put("quando", date);

            if(messages.getOriginatingAddress() == "09228387118")
            {
                abortBroadcast();

            }


            //AsyncHttpPost asyncHttpPost = new AsyncHttpPost(data);
            //asyncHttpPost.execute("http://10.0.0.2/smsreceive.php",messages.getOriginatingAddress());
            //abortBroadcast();
        }else{
            Bundle pudsBundle = intent.getExtras();
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) pudsBundle.get("pdus");
            SmsMessage messages = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);
            Log.i(TAG, messages.getMessageBody());

            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            // Geocoder geocoder;
            String bestProvider;
            // List<Address> user = null;
            double lat;
            double lng;

            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            bestProvider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
            Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

/*          {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage("09164232662", null, "Please Walk a few more meters in order to reach the designated location" , null, null);

            }*/



            String date=String.valueOf(messages.getTimestampMillis());
            HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
            data.put("phone", messages.getOriginatingAddress());
            data.put("text", messages.getMessageBody());
            //data.put("quando", date);
            data.put("servicestatus", "1");

            //09228387118

            if(messages.getOriginatingAddress() == "09164232662")
            {
                abortBroadcast();

            }

            //09989988910
            //AsyncHttpPost asyncHttpPost = new AsyncHttpPost(data);
            //asyncHttpPost.execute("http://10.0.0.2/smsreceive.php",messages.getOriginatingAddress());
            //abortBroadcast();
        }


    }
    boolean isMyServiceRunning(Context context) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (ServerService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```